# Type trait to receive T::value_type if present, T otherwise

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, type-traits

Required is a type trait for a type *T* providing a typedef *type* which is of type *T::value_type* if *T* has a typedef *value_type*, *T* otherwise.

I have tried the following implementation but it does not seem to work (typedef is always of type *T*, even if *T::value_type* is present):

```
template <class T, class = void> struct value_type { using type = T; };
template <class T> struct value_type<T, typename T::value_type> { using type = typename T::value_type; };

template <class T> using value_type_t = typename value_type<T>::type;

std::is_same_v<value_type_t<int>, int> // true
std::is_same_v<value_type_t<std::optional<int>>, int> // false, should be true
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specialization needs to match the base template.

Your base template has `class = void`, that means the second parameter in your specialization need to be void to match.

The way to do that is to use something like `std::void_t`, which will become void whatever we put in it. It's only purpose here is to allow SFINAE, if `T::value_type` is valid we always get `void`.

```
template <class T, class = void> struct value_type { using type = T; };
template <class T> struct value_type<T, std::void_t<typename T::value_type>> { using type = typename T::value_type; };

template <class T> using value_type_t = typename value_type<T>::type;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But why does it have to match `void`? I thought that the compiler will select the best matching specialization (`T::value_type` in this case) and will SFINAE it out if there is no `value_type` typedef and therefore resorts to the non-specialized version. The `void` as default parameter was (just) used to enable the `value_type_t` alias with a single parameter. Is there antoher way to implement this trait without the need of `void_t` (which was not there until C++17)?

Comment: @Lars Because that is how partial template specialization works. First the main template is instantiated, and then any specialization that matches the template parameters of the main one are considered valid. There are other ways if you do SFINAE without partial specialization (using return values of overloaded template functions for example), but in this case there is no cleaner or easier way AFAIK.

Comment: @Lars Take a look at how partial specialization works without SFINAE involved and I think you get a better idea of why it works the way it does. Mixing in SFINAE is just one way of using it, but it still needs to follow the same rules as any "normal" partial specialization.